# mysql php match multiple keywords

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables which are currently structured in the following way

```
Table: Images
image_id
image_title
...

Table: Keywords
keyword_id
keyword

Table: Image_Keyword
image_id
keyword_id
```

With this structure, I'm able to search if any images match any keywords using joins and or statements - however I would like to be able to retrieve images that have multiple keywords matches e.g. "keyword = ('red' or 'dress') and 'night'" - which would return all images that had either 'red' or 'dress' in them, alongside night.

Ideally I want to allow the user to be able to specify the AND and OR commands in the search box, which is why I have so far opted out of making separate joins for each new keyword - however I'm not sure how to proceed with the structuring of the query.

Currently I have the following, without the 'and' implementation:

```
SELECT i.* FROM images i
JOIN image_keyword ik ON i.id = ik.image_id
JOIN keywords k ON k.id = ik.keyword_id
WHERE k.keyword IN ('night','red')
```

Any help on how to go about creating the 'and' portion of this query would be greatly appreciated! Thanks kindly,

Dan

// UPDATE

So it looks as if I am going to have to do it by creating joins for each 'AND' request that I need to sort out - however I have an extension on the requirements now...

I have two other tables which follow the following structure

```
Table ImageData
id
image_id
caption_id
...

Table Caption
id
data (text)
```

In this instance, I would want to search for the keywords ('red','dress' and 'night'), using the same 'AND' and 'OR' capability as before, but also return the image if the text matches (using the same rules) in the caption data field. I would assume I potentially use an OR after the 'keyword' search, and then use a fulltext search on the caption, however I don't know if there is a cleaner way of combining the two, maybe even as two separate queries and then choosing the distinct results - which might allow for instances where the AND is successful in the keywords, and the OR is successful in the caption.

Any thoughts would be fantastic

Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you will end up is this -

1. One INNER JOIN for all your ORs.
2. One INNER JOIN each for all your ands.

For example -

```
SELECT i.* FROM images i
INNER JOIN image_keyword ik ON i.id = ik.image_id
INNER JOIN keywords kOR ON kOR.id = ik.keyword_id AND (kOR.keyword IN ('dress', 'red'))
INNER JOIN keywords kAND1 ON kAND1.id = ik.keyword_id AND kAND1.keyword = 'night'
```

PHP script would look something like.

```
$orKeywords = arrya('dress', 'red', 'white');
$andKeywords = array('night', 'day');
$orJoin = '';
$andJoin = '';
if(count($orKeywords) > 0)
{
    $orCondition = "'".implode("', '", $orKeywords)."'";
    $orJoin = " INNER JOIN keywords kOR ON kOR.id = ik.keyword_id AND kOR.keyword IN ($orCondition) ";
}
if(count($andKeywords) > 0)
{
    $cnt = 1;
    foreach($andKeywords as $keyword)
    {
        $andJoin .= " INNER JOIN keywords kAND{$cnt} ON kAND{$cnt}.id = ik.keyword_id AND kAND{$cnt}.keyword = '$keyword' ";$cnt++;
    }
}
$sql = "SELECT i.* FROM images i
INNER JOIN image_keyword ik ON i.id = ik.image_id
$orJoin
$andJoin";
```

You get the idea..

Comment: Hey - yeah thanks for that, I was thinking I might have to create a new join for each, although was really hoping that wouldn't have to be the case! I'll try it out and let you know - thanks kindly :)

Comment: Am having problems using this alongside the extra search as added onto the question above - is there anything you might be able to suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I would just generate the WHERE part of the query in PHP script, like this:

```
<?php
$entered_keywords = array('night','red');
$logic = 'OR'; // or 'AND'
$sql_where = implode(' '.$logic.' ', "k.keyword='$entered_keywords'"); //don't forget the escaping here!
$sql = 'SELECT i.* FROM images i
JOIN image_keyword ik ON i.id = ik.image_id
JOIN keywords k ON k.id = ik.keyword_id
WHERE '.$sql_where;
?>
```

Comment: I would do the generation of it in PHP, but its more a problem if I have three keywords, say "red", "dress" and "night" - if I want to find pictures that contain those exact keywords, an 'AND' wont do it in the current setup. As in the following query:

SELECT i.* FROM images i JOIN image_keyword ik ON i.id = ik.image_id
JOIN keywords k ON k.id = ik.keyword_id WHERE k.keyword = 'night' and k.keyword = 'red'

Comment: WHERE k.keyword = 'night' and k.keyword = 'red' and k.keyword = 'dress' ?